# Is there a contrasts() function in python (i.e., pandas) like in R?

Tags: python, r

Curious if there is a `contrasts()` function in python, which will show us how the variables have been dummyfied by R and how to interpret them in a model.

```
contrasts(data$Sex)
       male
female 0
  male 1

contrasts(data$Embarked)
  Q S
C 0 0
Q 1 0
S 0 1
```

Comment: Are you using `statsmodels` to run your models? There's some good documentation of how `statsmodels` does contrasts [here](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/contrasts.html).

Comment: TY @Marius This is partially what I was looking for, however the way in which R function works is that it takes a factor (Categorical - i.e., "Female"s & "Male"s) and essentially distills the variable to the unique items ("Female" & "Male") and then displays how the dummied values would be interpreted for the model. In Python, I guess? there is another step to be done first to dummy the variables to get it into that state of 0 & 1, then you contrast those levels via the Patsy contrasting func you passed. I guess I feel like R is doing a little more work for you when you factor a variable?